# Flutter: what is the best way of fetching a bunch of items and compiling them in order with FireStore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I will build the app by using `MVVM` model with `Flutter`.

So I fetch data **a** and data **b** from `fireStore` collection **A** and **B** each 1,000 items in `Repository`.

Then I compile this data **a** and **b** in `ViewModel` and make model called **AB**.

And lastly I show AB model in `View` and draw UI with **FutureBuilder** and **ListView.builder**.

But the problem is **speed**.

Before drawing the data in UI, I need to wait for 1,000 items to be fetched from fireStore and compiled.

That means the more data is stored, the more time will take.

When I use `ReactNative`, I used `Offset` concept.

So firstly I draw ListView.builder with 5 items first and if user scrolls down, I make it get 5 items more, something like this.

*-> If this is the way of Flutter as well with FireStore, I also need some example code.*

And when I use `Kotlin`, as soon as I get data from fireStore, with **onCompleteListener**, I draw UI directly.

What is the most efficient process for this in `flutter`?

And can you show some simple example code?

Comment: You might want to look at the documentation on paginating Firestore data with cursors: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Stream Builder in Nested Way. So Both of the Collection A and B will get Together. Problem is Future Builder is that he will show the after fetching all document of Query. But steam builder will show data how ever he get the data.